# At a Format Constraint to A Create Table Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, create-table

I am creating a table in SQL Server for one of my customers that is needing an Access DB converted to SQL Server. ON the tables Access has masked a column a certain way. They have a number lets say TP001111 and when I pull the value into SQL Server I get 1111. I have a table called VendorNumber and I need to format this number.

```
CREATE TABLE VendorNumber
(
  V_ID NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  V_Name NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

I have tried researching how to do this and I can't find a good example. What is the best way to have this value formatted when it is inserted into the table. I need to have it inserted as TP001111. The current code I have to format the column is:

```
UPDATE VendorNumber
SET V_ID = 'TP' + RIGHT((REPLICATE('0',6) + TPPRM_ID),6)
```

Comment: What is the point of a "TP" prefix when it is hard coded to always be the same? What is the datatype of TPPRM_ID?

Comment: The customer says they need it for their in house processing it has to be like that. The data type of it currently is NVARCHAR(8)

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code you posted? That is probably the simplest way to achieve what you say you are looking for.

Comment: Access can either store the masked data in the field, or add the mask characters to the raw data when returning results from a query, depending on a flag set in the mask definition. Afaik, SQL Server does not offer this functionality but you could probably use a trigger to achieve the same.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - you want to take value 'TP001111' from Access database and paste it as 'TP1111' MS SQL?

Comment: I want to pull it in to SQL Server using a CSV file and load it into the table as TP00111. Currently since the value is masked it is pulling in as 1111. I believe there is a way to have it change to TP001111 when you create the table definition without using a trigger.